# What is the reason for Sensitive But Unclassified (SBU)?

Tags: corporate-policy, sensitive-data-exposure

I've been reading about security classifications, and have a fundamental question I can't seem to find an answer to.  Why does the designation [Sensitive But Unclassified (SBU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitive_but_unclassified) exist?  Why not just classify it?

I can guess it may have to do with volume, but I don't know for sure.  Each classified document has some sort of tracking and lifetime rules/disposition procedures associated with it.  If we were to formally classify everything under SBU, that might mean tens of millions of records to keep track of.  Maybe SBU solves this volume problem, while protecting information.

Can anyone comment?

Answer (score 1):

This is not about the effort needed for classification, but that the sensitivity of the data is too low to be considered classified as confidential or higher (or other classifications schemes). It is still sensitive enough though to not make it publicly available. See also the extensive [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitive_but_unclassified) about it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the SBU marking is obsolete and is being replaced with CUI (Controlled Unclassified Information).

There are three pillars of controlled data:

- Confidentiality -- would damage occur if this data was leaked
- Integrity -- is the data safe from corruption
- Availability -- Is the data available when needed

For data to be controlled, it only needs one of these three pillars to be important.   For it to be classified, it must have a high confidentiality rating and a classification label.  To get a classification label, there must be a law or executive order or similar legal justification for the government to need to keep it confidential.

For example, confidentiality of the data might not be important to the government at all (making it unclassified), but it might contain personal data (PII) such as credit card information, where leakage would damage the related person financially or damage the privacy of their identity.

Another example of confidential but unclassified data would be proprietary or trade secret data, for which confidentiality is important to some (non-government) third party, but it has no justifiable high confidentiality classification in law.  Leaking this information is likely a breach of contract, but not a classified data breach.

Or, it could be public science data, which has no confidentiality (with requirements for it to be published), but it has medium or high integrity and availability requirements.  In other words, the OS must be secure to prevent malicious actors (or hardware failure) from modifying the data and maybe DoS protection to prevent attackers from making the data unavailable.

Comment: Thank you for correcting "sensitive" and how classification of data works.

Comment: I'm fuzzy on the "legal justification" part, I can't remember if it's only executive order or if there are other routes.  Clarification is welcome.